# Why does processing PApplet size restart the application?

Tags: java, processing

When I examined the logfiles of my processing application I noticed that at a certain point it restarts the application and then runs it to completion. I noticed that it happens when I issue the statement:

```
size (wwidth, wheight, OPENGL);
```

where wwidth = 1200 and wheight = 1000. When I move this statement to other spots the restart moment moves as well. Does anyone has any idea why this happens? How to prevent this as it takes at least 5 seconds of doing nothinh before the restart occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the `size()` function more than once in your sketch, then you're doing something wrong. From [the reference](https://processing.org/reference/size_.html):

> The size() function can only be used once inside a sketch, and it cannot be used for resizing.

Comment: Thanks! RTFM as usual :-). I have now made it the first statement of my sketch. Still a pity of the 5 seconds for the restart after using this function.